# Original source of Italian text for da Vinci quote

Tags: translation

I have read on many sites online, like Reddit and Goodreads, the following quote supposedly from da Vinci's notebooks:

“Principles for the Development of a Complete Mind: Study the science of art. Study the art of science. Develop your senses- especially learn how to see. Realize that everything connects to everything else.”

― Leonardo da Vinci

And I have even tried to find the original Italian text from which this quote was translated but was a bit limited to my knowledge of Italian. When it has been quoted in documents like this one from a museum dedicated to him, it seems to be in 'modern' Italian and not what would have been written in da Vinci's time: https://www.leonardoagradisca.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/catalogo_mddleonardo_en.pdf

> "Per sviluppare una mente completa studia la scienza dell'arte, studia l'arte della scienza. Sviluppa i tuoi sensi, impara soprattutto a vedere. Comprendi che tutto è connesso."

Leonardo Da Vinci

So I am trying to track down where this quote actually comes from, which is strange because if it is attributed to such a famous person like da Vinci then it should be easy to locate from searching Italian websites. Are there any reliable references in Italian that can be used to verify this attribution?

Comment: Yeah, the text doesn't feel sixteenth century at all too me. I suspect someone just made it up.

Comment: This was already asked by the same contributor (and the question was deleted as off-topic): https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/reference-for-leonardo-da-vinci-quote

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic. Skeptics.SE, perhaps?

Comment: @DaG I asked the question at Skeptics.SE regarding whether this was a da Vinci quote (but didn't really get an answer), so I am asking for original Italian text where this quote might have come from.

Comment: But you already asked it here and it was already deleted.